# Create view with jpa eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm working with two databases and I want a column in table1 of the first database to make reference

to a row in table2 in the second database. I'm asking if I could create a view to select columns from

database1 and database2, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, the JPA has access to mapping native queries which (is probably) the easiest way to do this "across catalogs" in my mind. There is probably an easier way to do it, I just can't think of it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sample of the Eclipse site?

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite

With composite pattern you can use Two or more persistence units combined into a single persistence Unit.

[image]